# Why there is no orderBy(Collection<Field> fields) method in jooq?

Tags: database, jooq

In Jooq api there are

```
...
SelectSeekStepN<R> orderBy(Collection<? extends SortField<?>> fields);

SelectSeekStepN<R> orderBy(Field<?>... fields);
...
```

Why there is no

```
SelectSeekStepN<R> orderBy(Collection<? extends Field<?>>
```

This makes it effectively inconsistent with `groupBy()` method agruments.

There are methods:

```
SelectHavingStep<R> groupBy(GroupField... fields);
SelectHavingStep<R> groupBy(Collection<? extends GroupField> fields);
```

Every `Field` implements `GroupField` so I can call it with `Collection<Field>` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prior to jOOQ 3.10, there has been a method of the signature

```
orderBy(Collection<? extends SortField<?>>)
```

Which unfortunately you could not use because [`SortField`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/SortField.html) is not a super type of [`Field`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html). This was fixed with [#6327](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6327) in jOOQ 3.10, when a new [`OrderField`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/OrderField.html) type was introduced, which is a super type to both of the previous types. The existing `orderBy` method was retrofitted to now accept the super type of your collection:

```
orderBy(Collection<? extends OrderField<?>>)
```

... which means you can now pass a `List<Field<?>>` to the method.

Comment: It seems like this inconsistency is fixed in *3.10* using `OrderField` interface which is implemented by `Field`.

Comment: In pre 3.10 version I couldn't pass `Collection<Field>` into `orderBy()`. `Field` doesn't implement `SortField`. (But I could pass `Field[]` because there is `orderBy(Field[].. fields)` - that is weird)    

Now in 3.10 I can pass `Collection<Field>` because there is a new method in API: `orderBy(Collection<? extends OrderField> fields)` and `Field` now implements `OrderField` (there was no `OrderField` interface in 3.9 ).

Comment: Oh, I see, I'm sorry. Yes of course, you're perfectly right. That was the very reason for introducing `OrderField` :) I'll fix the answer...